# std::transform in copying data from json array to a float array C++

Tags: c++, json, stl

I have a json array as shown below

```
{
  { "Data":[1.0, 2.0, 3.0] }
}
```

I am trying to copy this json array to a float array using `std::transform`.

In code -

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <memory>

using json = nlohmann::json;
int main(){
    json tensor;
    tensor["Data"] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };

    auto dataPtr = std::make_unique<float[]>(3);

    const auto& dataVec = tensor["Data"];
    std::transform(dataVec.cbegin(), dataVec.cend(), dataPtr, [](float data) { return data; });
}
```

Error -

```
cannot increment value of type 'std::unique_ptr<float[]>'
```

**Question** - How do I use std::transform in this case, where I dont have an iterator

Comment: you do have an iterator. Its a unique pointer of a float array, you can use a pointer to first element as iterator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::transform` may not be able to increment the `unique_ptr` itself, but you can get the contained pointer. The raw pointer is incrementable, so it is usable as a target for the transform:

`std::transform(dataVec.cbegin(), dataVec.cend(), dataPtr.get(), [](float data) { return data; });`

Comment: If `std::unique_ptr` is the proper tool, then `get()` member is the proper accessor. But I can't judge from the snippet in the OP snippet. The mismatch between source and destination size is a concern, though destination is larger in current snippet.

Comment: @Red.Wave, have corrected the destination size, it is 3

Comment: @Nitron_707,  you should retrieve the size from source, instead of hard coding it. `nlohmann` seems to be using `std::vector` as the underlying type for its arrays: therefore the `size` method should be available as well as `std::size` and `std::ranges::size`. I would actually prefer `std::vector<float>` for its convenient range/iterator API; Because with pointers you'll always need an extra object to keep track of size/end of your array.